# Opening, closing and displaying one webpage from another

Tags: javascript

**ENVIRONMENT**

Chrome

Version 43.0.2357.81 m

**JAVASCRIPT**

webpage1

var windowHandle;

function1

windowHandle = window.open("webpage2.html");

function2

windowHandle.close();

**PROBLEM:**

The code works fine but webpage2 doesn't have focus when it opens. I've tried using windowHandle.focus() to bring it up after it is opened but no joy. I could use an anchor tag with an href to open the page but I don't know how to get a handle on it that way to close it. Just a bit confused at this point. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function() { windowHandle.focus(); }, 1)`, it should do the trick.

Comment: Well, that sounded good, but Dev Tools in Chrome says that focus() is undefined for windowHandle.